# How to add newly added listitems from Top. sql server

Tags: java, android

I want add newly added listitems from the index 0. like if one items is present already then if i insert another item so i want it display at top.

```
  ListView lst1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
     List<Map<String, String>> MyDataList = null;
     reuestitems myData = new reuestitems();
     MyDataList = myData.getlist10();
     String[] from = {"bloodgrp", "date", "time", "name", "Username"};
     int[] to = {R.id.listt, R.id.date, R.id.time1, R.id.name3, R.id.user};
     ad = new SimpleAdapter(request.this, MyDataList, R.layout.listrequest, from, to);
     lst1.setAdapter(ad);

       lst1.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
     if(ad.getCount()==0){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No requests are currently visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i strongly suggest to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.
the function you are looking for is `adapter.notifyItemInserted` or if you want to remove an item `adapter.notifyItemRemoved`.

Comment: But i have used listview so there is any function that can be used.

Comment: i had the same problem and didn't found any solution , finally i switched to recycler View.